How to prevent VS Code from splitting floating windows in-half when opening a new file by press CTRL + P?
I'm having a problem in VSCODE directly with floating windows. Whenever I open a new file by pressing Ctrl + P it splits the new file of the floating window instead opening the file separately (which how VScode is supposed to work)
I searched a lot and I tried many solutions but nothing is working, whenever I open VS code then adds floating window, Ctrl + p works like is should, then after a day or two it behaves strangely, it splits the window in half, any solutions?

In the Ctrl-P window you are hitting Enter and not Ctrl+Enter?  Ctrl+Enter will make a new group (i.e., split) the chosen file, just Enter should not.  If you are just hitting Enter, let us know, there are other things to examine why the wrong command is being triggered.

Hello Mark, thank you for the answer and yes I'm hitting Enter and not Ctrl+Enter as I'm aware that Ctrl+Enter will split the window in half, there could be other things like certain Extentions may trigger the issue I'm dealing with but to assure I disabled all the Extentions and still I'm having this problem.

Run the command: Developer: Toggle Keyboards Shortcuts Troubleshooting and see what command vscode is triggering.  Obviously, some split command but there might be some helpful info there.

Thank you for the suggestion, I will observe the command output and if I find anything helpful to the problem I have, I will reply with a feedback.
